# JQuery silent refresh with codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how I can use this:

`setInterval(function() { $('#myDiv').load('contentToLoad.php');}, 5000);`

with codeigniter. I have tried this:

```
setInterval(function() { $('.images').load('<?=base_url();?>user/profile/<?=$posts->profile?>');}, 5000);
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried to do some research and haven't found any good examples on how to do this with codeigniter. Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: any errors in console??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this

```
setInterval(function() { $('.images').load('<?=site_url('user/profile/' . $posts->profile);?>');}, 5000);
```